# why it is showing instance of future? how to get data

Tags: flutter, api, sharedpreferences

```
 Future<void> setEmpId(String empId) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(this.empId, empId);
  }

Future<String> getEmpId() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String empId;
    empId = await prefs.getString(this.empId) ?? '';
    return empId;
  }

Prefs().setEmpId(state.empVerifyEntity.employee.empId);//set empId from api

In Another Class:
class Page extends State<Page>{

 Future<void> getEmpId() async {
    String empId = await Prefs().getEmpId().toString();
    print("----------->>>>>>>>$empId");
  }
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getEmpId();
  }
}
```

Here I'm getting instance of future, I tried every method like .then(value) Each and every method I'm getting instance of future. how to data correctly?

Comment: Why are you converting the result from getEmpId with toString?

Comment: to get string as a response, empid is String

Comment: But you return `String` in `getEmpId()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to the fact that your initState method is synchronous and the method in which you are getting the value for EmpId isn't.

Therefore, it is not waiting for the result of the call.

You can accomplish this in several ways:

1. Add a then clause to the call of getEmpId

   ```
   @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getEmpId().then((result) {
      //your logic here
      )
    }
   ```
2. Add a PostFrameCallback

   ```
       @override
       void initState() {
        super.initState();
         WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
           getEmpId();
        });
       }
   ```

Comment: I'm getting value after reloading, before reloading it is null why? I'm using bloc

Comment: Where are you setting the empId value? You did not mention you are using bloc in your question.